# How should i load content from different webpage in iframe of main page by clicking on card?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, dynamic

I have try to create recipe website.which have formate like ,at header section there is "nav bar" and below that is my content box which i mark as flex and added two child container,one for cards which contains  recipe name, brief details and image of food and other other container contains one iframe where complete detail of recipe should come whenever user click on card.
I want to only reload iframe  whenever user click on card of recipe. Not to navigate it to others page. Other page content should change as i click on other card inside iframe.

I had tried basic approach by give anchor tag at bottom of card to "learn more" which direct to different page. And added same page in iframe.but it reloading to new tab or next page. I have only use html and css.